# Two matrices are similar if and only if the companion matrices are equal

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A,B \in M_n(F)$ and $A,B: F^{n \times 1} \rightarrow F^{n \times 1}$ linear operators. Suppose that $F^{n \times 1}$ is both $A$-cyclic and $B$-cyclic. Prove that $A$ is similar to $B$ if and only if their companion matrices $C(f_A)$ and $C(f_B)$ are equal.

One direction is easy to show: if $A,B$ are similar, then they are the same characteristic polynomial. Hence their companion matrices are the same. But I don't know how to prove the other direction. Being $A$-cyclic means their exists a vector $v$ such that $\{v,Av,\ldots,A^{n-1}v\}$ is a basis for $F^{n \times 1}$, but how do I use that in my proof?

Comment: There is a theorem saying that $A$ is similar to its companion matrix if and only if $F^n$ is $A$-cyclic. Do you know it?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: No, but which theorem is it? I could look it up.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix#Characterization So it's "enough" to prove one implication of this equivalence.

Comment: @user112358 Could you please tell the book containing the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We only have to show that the companion matrix of $A$ is similar to $A$ if $F^n$ is $A$-cyclic. To prove this, let $v_0 := v,\;v_1 := Av,\,\ldots\,,v_{n-1}:=A^{n-1}v$. Then $\{v_0,\ldots,v_{n-1}\}$ is a basis of $F^n$. Let $C$ be the representation of $A$ with respect to this basis. It looks very similar as the companion matrix. The first $n-1$ columns are the same. The last column has the form $[\mu_0,\ldots,\mu_{n-1}]^T$, where the $\mu_i$'s are defined by $Av_{n-1} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mu_iv_i$. Now, there is a non-singular matrix $S$ such that $A = SCS^{-1}$. Therefore, the characteristic polynomials of $C$ and $A$ coincide. Now, it remains for you to show that $-\mu_i$ is the $i$-th coefficient of the characteristic polynomial of $C$. Then you know that $C = C(f_A)$ and hence $A = SC(f_A)S^{-1}$.

Comment: Your approach seems clear to me. But is there an elegant way to show that $\mu_i$ are the coefficients of $C(f_A)$? Or should I just compute the determinant?

Comment: Well, maybe you know already that the characteristic polynomials of $A$ and $C(f_A)$ coincide. Then the claim follows from the fact that $C$ and $C(f_A)$ are equal in the first $n-1$ columns. Otherwise I'm afraid you will have to calculate the determinant.